# Jmeter- Log values to CSV file

Tags: jmeter

I have used below code to log values to CSV. With this code I am not able to get header names, it directly logging values to firstname, lastname without header. I am expecting the output file with header and values. For example: Can some please let me know whats missing

firstname lastname
Test      Jmeter

```
firstNameoutput = vars.get(“firstName”)
lastNameoutput = vars.get(“lastName”)
resultPath = vars.get(“resultsheetFilePath”)
FileOutputStream file= new FileOutputStream(resultPath, true);
PrintStream printOutputData = new PrintStream(file);
this.interpreter.setOut(printOutputData);
Var responseCode=prev.getResponseCode();

If (responseCode.equals(“200”){
print(“PASS”+”+firstName+”,”+lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write `firstname` and `lastname` as the first line of the CSV file somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test).

As [since JMeter 3.1 Groovy is the recommended scripting option](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) add a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread group and put the following code there:

```
new File(vars.get('resultsheetFilePath')).text = 'firstname,lastname' + System.getProperty('line.separator')
```

This will create the file with the header at the beginning of the test and you can write the values later.